# Android app error - You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api, google-cloud-billing

I have an Android app where I display nearby hospitals using Google Map. I am using Maps & Places API.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.2649519,76.6208733&radius=10000&type=hospital&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY`

I have enabled billing for my account. I have linked the account to my project. The app was working fine. However when I check it now, it gives me error

`{   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}`

My billing account is active. I have not done any changes to the code nor to my billing account. I have not set any application or API restrictions on my API key.

I created a new billing account and linked it to the project to check if there was any problem with my old billing account. I am getting the same error.

Comment: For the "API key not valid" issue, it appears that you are using a Server key, but you need to use a browser key. The Vision API Getting Started page has detailed screenshots. go through the link https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart#setting_up_an_api_key

Comment: I am not getting "invalid key" error. I selected the "Create Credentials"-> API Key option and generated the API key.

Comment: It would be best to directly reach out to [Google Maps Support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case) for issues like this.

Comment: Hi Sahana, did you find a solution to the problem you mentioned above? Even I'm facing the same issue and getting the following error: {   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

Comment: Hello Arjun. I contacted the Google Maps Support team as per the reply from smga08. They resolved the issue. This is the reply I got from them:                       "As I’ve checked here your billing account is in INR which the Maps project is linked with. Maps projects will only work in a USD billing account, so what you need to do is create a new billing account in USD currency. Just make sure that you select your country for the Country and also select google maps platform to make sure you create it right"

Comment: Arjun, these are the steps:Create a new billing account for Google Maps Platform

1.Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2.Open the left-side menu and select Billing.
3.Click the name of your existing billing account near the top of the page, and then click Manage billing accounts.
4.Click Create account.
5.Enter the name of the new billing account and choose which business the billing account will pay for (in this case Google Maps Platform).
6.Click Submit and enable billing.

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the *@Sahana Kamath* comment **this issue was solved by Google Maps Support team**.

> As I’ve checked here your billing account is in INR which the Maps project is linked with. **Maps projects will only work in a USD billing account, so what you need to do is create a new billing account in USD currency**. Just make sure that you select your country for the Country and also select google maps platform to make sure you create it right.

Also, accordingly to the documentation [About currencies and Cloud Billing accounts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency#about-currencies):

> **Each Cloud Billing account operates in a single currency**, which you cannot change after you create your Cloud Billing account. *If you
> need a Cloud Billing account to operate in a currency different than
> the currency of your existing Cloud Billing account, you will need to*
> [set up a new Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account).

In addition, please have a look at the documentation [Getting started with Google Maps Platform](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started) and [Google Maps Platform Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing).